# Не работает long-poll vk_api

Tags: python, vkontakte-api, long-poll

Делал чат бота на pythone с модулем vk_api, проблема с longpoll:

```py
import vk_api
account = vk_api.VkApi(token='grouptoken')
from vk_api.longpoll import VkLongPoll, VkEventType
longpoll = VkLongPoll(account)
vk = account.get_api()
rand = 0
for event in longpoll.listen(): 
    print('event in longpoll.listen') #для отладки
    if event.type == VkEventType.MESSAGE_NEW and event.to_me and event.text:
        print('new message') #для отладки
        if event.from_user: 
                    print('user message')  #для отладки
                    vk.messages.send( 
                      user_id=event.user_id,
                      message='ответ',
                      random_id = rand) 
        elif event.from_chat:
            print('chat message') #для отладки
            vk.messages.send( 
                       chat_id=event.chat_id,
                       message='ответ',
                       random_id = rand )
```

в ЛС группы все работает, но в беседе нет, доступ к переписке и права администратора у группы есть. В консоли сообщения идут только при написании в ЛС, при сообщении в беседе реакции нет ни на одной ступени. Что могло пойти не так?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Это из-за `VkLongPoll`.

В [документации](https://vk-api.readthedocs.io/en/latest/longpoll.html) указано, что это модуль для пользователей.
Так как Вы авторизуетесь с ключом сообщества, Вам требуется `VkBotLongPoll` (и соответственно `VkBotEventType`).

Обратите внимание на то, что он находится в другом модуле, а именно в `vk_api.bot_longpoll`.

***Пример:***

```py
from vk_api import VkApi
from vk_api.bot_longpoll import VkBotLongPoll, VkBotEventType


vk_session = VkApi(token='access_token')
longpoll = VkBotLongPoll(vk_session, 'group_id')


def main():
    for event in longpoll.listen():
        if event.type == VkBotEventType.MESSAGE_NEW:
            ...


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Comment: Взял ваш код для своей группы, только начал изучать питон. Хочу переделать ваш код, но не могу понять, как сделать, чтобы бот отвечал на сообщения нужным ответом, например "Привет"