# проблема с vk_api на python

Tags: python, vkontakte-api, бот

Вообщем, дело в том что код выдает ошибку - `AttributeError: 'Event' object has no attribute 'chat_id'` с user_id все прекрасно работает, бот так же работает. Если можно как-нибудь по другому писать от лица бота в беседу, жду предложений. Заранее спасибо!

```
import random

import requests
import vk_api
from vk_api.longpoll import VkLongPoll, VkEventType

from commander.commander import Commander

def write_msg(chat_id, message):
    vk.method('messages.send', {'chat_id': chat_id, 'message': message, 'random_id': random.randint(0, 2048)})


token = "указан"
vk = vk_api.VkApi(token = token, login = 'указан', password = 'указан')
longpoll = VkLongPoll(vk)


x = ["февраля","января","марта","апреля","мая","июня", "июля","августа","сентября","октября","ноября","декабря"]
mood  = ["Хорошо","Отлично","Плохо","Бывало и лучше"]
uch = []


commander = Commander()
long_message = ""
print("Бот запущен")

messages = vk.method("messages.getConversations", {"offset": 0, "count": 1})
while True:
    for event in longpoll.listen():


        if event.type == VkEventType.MESSAGE_NEW:


            if event.to_me:


                request = event.text


                if request == "Бот" or request == "Бот, что ты умеешь" or request == "Бот, что ты делаешь" or request == "что ты делаешь" or request == "чир иы умеешь" or request == "Начать":
                    write_msg(event.chat_id, "Приветсвую! Все команды производятся через Бот, пример: Бот, как дела. Вот что я могу - 1. ... 2. ...")
                elif request == "Бот, конституция":
                    write_msg(event.chat_id, long_message)
                elif request == "Бот, как дела":
                    randmood = random.choice(mood)
                    write_msg(event.chat_id, randmood)
                elif request == "Бот, когда произойдет":
                    random2 = random.randrange(1,30,1)
                    random3 = random.randrange(2018,2035,1)
                    random4 = random.choice(x)
                    random5 = random.randrange(0,23,1)
                    random6 = random.randrange(0,59,1)
                    random7 = random.randrange(0,59,1)
                    s = str(random2)+str(" ")+str(random4)+str(", ")+str(random3)+str(" года, в ")+str(random5)+str(" час(ов), ")+str(random6)+str(" минут(у), ")+str(random7)+str( " секунд(у).")
                    write_msg(event.chat_id, s)
                elif request.split()[0] == "command":
                    write_msg(event.chat_id, commander.do(request[8::]))
```

Comment: Можно использовать `peer_id`. Но для начала стоило бы показать код, который приводит к ошибке.

Comment: ``` Бот запущен
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/Lunatrius/vk_bot.py", line 44, in <module>
    write_msg(event.chat_id, "Приветсвую! Все команды производятся через Бот, пример: Бот, как дела. Вот что я могу - 1. ... 2. ...")
AttributeError: 'Event' object has no attribute 'chat_id' ```

Comment: Вы привели ошибку и трассировку стека. Хорошо. Но нужен и код, который эту ошибку вызывает. Приведите, пожалуйста, исходный текст программы. Мне кажется, дело в том, что Вы используете `API` для пользователей, но я не могу быть в этом уверен, не видя Ваш код.

Comment: Возможно, `event["object"]["chat_id"]`.

Comment: event["object"]["chat_id"] не помог, весь код выше

Comment: Какой токен Вы используете? В плане того, откуда Вы его взяли. Если это токен сообщества, то Вам следует переписать бота, используя модуль `bot_longpoll`.

Comment: Я получил его в сообществе, работа с API

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Не работает long-poll vk\_api](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1026856/%d0%9d%d0%b5-%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%b1%d0%be%d1%82%d0%b0%d0%b5%d1%82-long-poll-vk-api)

Comment: nomnoms12, какой вид текста используется для VkBotMessageEvent?
(request = event.text)

Comment: @Дмитрий `event.obj['text']`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Это из-за `VkLongPoll`.

В [документации](https://vk-api.readthedocs.io/en/latest/longpoll.html) указано, что это модуль для пользователей.
Так как Вы авторизуетесь с ключом сообщества, Вам требуется `VkBotLongPoll` (и соответственно `VkBotEventType`).

Обратите внимание на то, что он находится в другом модуле, а именно в `vk_api.bot_longpoll`.

---

Вам придётся переписать некоторую часть кода, вот самое главное:

- ***Авторизация***

На этом этапе Вам не нужен логин и пароль, достаточно только токена:

```py
vk_session = VkApi(token='[access_token]')
```

- ***Получение `LongPoll` сервера***

Здесь Вам дополнительно понадобится `id` сообщества:

```py
longpoll = VkBotLongPoll(vk_session, '[group_id]')
```

- ***Получение сообщений***

Используйте `VkBotEventType`:

```py
for event in longpoll.listen():
    if event.type == VkBotEventType.MESSAGE_NEW:
```

- ***Отправка сообщения***

Для того чтобы бот работал и в ЛС и в беседе, используйте `peer_id` (вместо `chat_id` и `user_id`). Получить его можно следующим образом:

```py
peer_id = event.obj['peer_id']
```