# Бот ВК не отвечает на сообщение

Tags: python, vkontakte-api

Я создал токен, включил сообщения сообщества, включил возможности ботов.

Запускаю скрипт в PyCharm, но при написании сообщения боту он не отвечает.

Вот код:

```
import random

import vk_api
from vk_api.longpoll import VkLongPoll, VkEventType

vk_session = vk_api.VkApi(token='токен')


longpoll_session = VkLongPoll(vk_session)


vk = vk_session.get_api()


global random_answer


def random_id():
    random_answer = 0
    random_answer += random.randint(0, 1000000000)
    return random_answer

while True:
    for event in longpoll_session.listen():
        if event.type == VkEventType.MESSAGE_NEW and event.to_me():
            if event.text.lower() == 'привет':
                vk.messages.send(
                    user_id=event.user_id,
                    message='Привет!!!!',
                    random_id=random_id()
                )
```

Я впервые работаю с vk_api, поэтому мог не учесть чего-то банального. Надеюсь на вашу помощь. Заранее спасибо.

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Не работает long-poll vk\_api](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1026856/%d0%9d%d0%b5-%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%b1%d0%be%d1%82%d0%b0%d0%b5%d1%82-long-poll-vk-api)

Comment: Обратите внимание на [один из моих ответов](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1026857/339283). Возможно, это поможет Вам.

Comment: @nomnoms12, большое спасибо за Ваш комментарий, но, к сожалению, это не помогло.

Comment: В настройках сообщества, а именно на вкладке «Работа с API», Вы не забыли подписаться на события `LongPoll` (и в принципе включить его)? Нужно поставить галочку напротив «Входящие сообщения». Если Вы это сделали, но бот не работает, приведите, пожалуйста, в вопрос обновлённый код (нажав кнопку [edit]). Возможно, куда-то ещё закралась ошибка.

Comment: 6-я строчка кода(с учетом пробелов), ты токен сообщества указал?