# LongPoll не присылает ивенты с бесед (vk_api)

Tags: python, vkontakte-api

Основываясь на этой статье: https://habr.com/ru/post/428507/ написал код для бота в вк и начал тестить. Также пользовался примерами отсюда https://github.com/python273/vk_api.

```
from vk_api.longpoll import VkLongPoll, VkEventType
import requests
import vk_api
from vk_api.utils import get_random_id

vk_session = vk_api.VkApi(token='Здесь токен группы')
longpoll = VkLongPoll(vk_session)
vk = vk_session.get_api()
for event in longpoll.listen():
    print('Чекаем сервер')
    if event.type == VkEventType.MESSAGE_NEW and event.to_me and event.text:
        print('Пришло сообщение')
        if event.text == 'бип' or event.text == 'боп':
            print('Знакомое')
            if event.from_user:
                print('отправлю ка ответ')
                vk.messages.send(
                    random_id=get_random_id(),
                    user_id=event.user_id,
                    message='бап'
                )
            elif event.from_chat:
                print('отправлю ка ответ')
                vk.messages.send(
                    chat_id=event.chat_id,
                    message='буп',
                    random_id=get_random_id(),
                )
```

Работает, если пишет пользователь в личку, но не работает (расставил везде print, чтобы знать точно), если пишут в беседе. Причём сервер даже и не отправляет уведомления о сообщении. 
Сразу уточню несколько моментов:
1. При создании токена я дал разрешение на всё возможное.
2. Доступ к сообщениям открыт, а возможность пригласить бота в беседы включена.
3. У бота есть права администратора в беседе.
4. LongPoll включён, и тип ивентов "Входящие сообщения" тоже

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Не работает long-poll vk\_api](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1026856/%d0%9d%d0%b5-%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%b1%d0%be%d1%82%d0%b0%d0%b5%d1%82-long-poll-vk-api)

Comment: Посмотрите [один из моих ответов](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1026857/339283), возможно, это поможет Вам.

Comment: @nomnoms12 Я использовал этот пример https://github.com/python273/vk_api/blob/master/examples/bot_longpoll.py, заменив токен и айди группы на своё, но ничего не вышло, боту по-прежнему ничего не приходит

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Дьявол, как обычно, кроется в мелочах. Для решения проблемы нужно было поставить новейшую версию LongPoll в настройках сообщества. Я рекомендую (на данный момент) поставить версию 5.102 вместо 5.103, т.к. в 5.103 есть проблемы с получением информации (имя написавшего, текст сообщения, возможно ещё какие-то). Также следовало использовать модуль VkBotLongPoll, а не VkLongPoll.
Подробнее про VkBotLongPoll:
[Не работает long-poll vk_api](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1026856/%d0%9d%d0%b5-%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%b1%d0%be%d1%82%d0%b0%d0%b5%d1%82-long-poll-vk-api/1026857#1026857)
https://vk-api.readthedocs.io/en/latest/bot_longpoll.html
https://github.com/python273/vk_api/blob/master/examples/bot_longpoll.py